# OOP/JAVA: Does assinging an object to another changes its attributes(class variables) too?

Tags: java, oop, object, pass-by-reference

So my question is if an object `A` has an attribute such as `int var;` and object `B` has an attribute `int var2` both of the object are instantiated from the same class using the same constructor. For illustrations purposes lets say that `var=3` and `var2=0` Does assigning object `A=B` make `A.var==0` ? please do motivate your answer for me.

here is more code in case you need more:

```
public class CarSize{
    public CarSize(int x)
    {
        this.var=x;
    }
    public void call()
    {

        doubleVar(this);

    }
    private void doubleVar(CarSize cz)
    {
        int vara= cz.getVar()*2;
        CarSize c= new CarSize(vara);
        cz=c;

    }
    public int getVar(){return this.var;}
    private int var;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        CarSize cz = new CarSize(3);
        cz.call();
        System.out.println(cz.getVar());
    }

}
```

**ANNOUNCEMENT**

people please check the code before attemtpting to explain to me what i already know, thanks a lot for your understanding.

Comment: Well, this is not changing the field in A, assignment just makes A point to same place as B, so yes, this field will become the same as in B

Comment: but it doesnt, at least the code that i showed says otherwise, i mean it came as a shock to me

Comment: And what are you expecting? That your code will return 6? Can't fully get the logic. And I would also suggest cz = new CarSize(vara); without a temporary object

Comment: @Semant1ka yes i was expecting 6, thank god someone actually read my code before typing a comment on it. what is wrong with my logic there, i mean if `A.var= 1` and `B.var =2` and i say `A=B`shouldnt `A.var`be =2 since `A` is now pointing to the same address as `B` and old values of `A` will get garbage collected?

Comment: in seems that @Sweeper gives you a good point on why it is not working

Answer (score 2):

The problem why your code does not work as expected lies at this short one of code:

```
cz=c;
```

Since `CarSize` is a reference type, variables of `CarSize` store "pointers" to `CarSize` objects, not the `CarSize` objects themselves.

When you are passing a car size as a parameter, you are passing a "pointer". `cz=c` makes the pointer stored in `cz` point to the same object as that stored in `c`.

Now let's see how you call this method:

```
doubleVar(this);
```

`this` refers to the `cz` that is declared in the main method. Again, `this` points to a car size object. In the `doubleVar` method, you made the parameter point to another object, but you only made the *parameter* point to something else. `this` is never changed, neither did its fields.

That's why you don't see the values doubling.

To fix this, don't assign the parameter a new value. Instead, change `this` directly. Get rid of the parameter because that is not needed.

```
private void doubleVar()
{
    this.var *= 2; // you can actually omit "this.", I put it there just to make it clear for you

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a reference to an object to another object, you cannot assign an object to another object. In your case both A and B would reference the same object previously referenced by only B. Object referenced previously by A will be taken by the garbage collector and cease to exist.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, using the `=` operator with non-primitives results in aliasing. If you have two different objects of the same class, `a` and `b`, saying `a = b;` makes `a` the same object as `b`, and garbage collection will eventually destroy what used to be in `a`.

So, yes, the field will be the same, but changing `a`'s value of the field will also change `b`'s value of the field because `a` and `b` are now the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    object a = new object(3);
    object b = new object(0);

    a = b;
    System.out.println(a.var);
  }
}


public class object{

  protected int var;
  public object(int x){
     var = x;
  }
}
```

This is code of the situation you described exactly. The output here would be "0" because when a programmer defined object is set equal to another object of the same type it overwrites the reference from the original value of 3 to the new value of 0